# How do you escape characters in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

> **Possible Duplicates:** 
>   *[Escape single quotes in jQuery or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083646)* 
>   *[Escape dynamic strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738591)*

How do you assign a string, in this case it's HTML code, to a JavaScript / jQuery variable?

And how do you escape double quotes and single quotes properly?

```
var html = ""; // <-- HTML goes here
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question further, maybe include an full example of what exactly it is your trying to accomplish? As it stands I have no idea what your asking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`var html = "<head><title>Hello in \"quotes\"<\/title><\/head>"`

Comment: Note that js strings can be delimited by single quotes or double quotes, and chars of the non-delimiting quote type do not need to be escaped. That is, both `var html = '<head><title>Hello in "quotes"<\/title><\/head>` and `var html = "<head><title>Hello in 'quotes'<\/title><\/head>"` are valid without escaping any characters in the string. See [String Literals at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#String_Literals) for more about it.

Comment: of course, I just wanted to show an example of how escaping works in a string